# JSF Unique id inside <p:panelGrid>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

In JSF 2.0 how to add a unique id inside

```
<p:panelGrid>       
<p:inputText id="unq1" value="{...}" />

<unique id for all components below>
...
...
</unique id for all components below> // till here
</p:panelGrid>
```

I do have a few components inside `<p:panelGrid>`, I would like to have a unique id for all the JSF components inside  except for the first component which is `id="unq1"`

Comment: Not sure what you want, but there is no lot possibilities. Or you will assign ids manually, or you will not assign id attribute and let JSF generate ids.

Comment: JSF adds by default its own unique id. You can also assign them specifying your own id's.

Comment: @partlov Say if I have multiple `inputText`, is there any way I can assign id for all `inputText` with one unique id?

Comment: @XtremeBiker See my above comment.

Comment: No that would really not be an id :) ID per every component (or xml tag)

Comment: @Polppan , do you want a prefix for those ids ? Why do you need this behavior ? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Daniel I have Primefaces `<p:ajax update=""`, I was wondering if I can give one unique id for `update` rather than multiple id sepearted by spaces.

Comment: @Polppan , if you want to update a set of elements , why not wrapping then with `<h:panelGroup id="someId"` and using `<p:ajax update="someId"` ? or why not assigning them all with unique `styleClass` and using `<p:ajax update="@(.myUniqueStyleClass)"` ?

Comment: @Daniel yes `styleclass` would be a good option. I tried with `<h:panelGroup` however alignment of all components got messed up. If put as an answer I will be glad to accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update a set of elements , why not wrapping then with

```
<h:panelGroup id="someId"
```

and using

```
<p:ajax update="someId"
```

Or why not assigning them all with unique `styleClass="myUniqueStyleClass"` and using

```
<p:ajax update="@(.myUniqueStyleClass)"
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of achieving this, is to create a custom tag to generate a random string (store it in a variable) and then use it as a prefix for sub/child components that are inside the panelGrid.

For example:

```
<p:panelGrid>
<p:inputText id="unq1" value="{...}" />

<myTag:createId var="myNewId"/>  --> Generate and Store the Id in Var

<h:inputText id="#{myNewId}-text"/> -->Use the var as prefix and create new id's.
...
...
</panelGrid>
```

NOTE: This is not the best approach, as it might still cause collisions.